# Error:couldn't initialize class SK.gnome.twain.TwainManager

Tags: twain

I bought the license for Morena - Image Acquisition Framework version 6.0.1.0. when I want to run applet in web browsers there is below error

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class SK.gnome.twain.TwainManager

Can somebody please advise on what can be done.
Please,help me

Answer (score 0):

I hope you solved it after so much time, but I'll try to answer the question, because google direct me here.

There are two possible problems:

- List item Like is said in [support page](http://www.gnome.sk/Twain/jtp_support.html) - The cause of this error is often in the license. Your trial license may have expired, for example.
- List item Other possibility is your jdk version, you can solve it installing an old jdk version.